# Is the device token for an archived build installed via Apple TestFlight different from one installed via Xcode built with the same Scheme?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, azure, apple-push-notifications

Same device, iOS 8, iPhone 6+. I'm seeing two different device IDs (I have debug disabled running from Xcode, and it is exactly the same scheme I use to build the archive I'm installing via TestFlight), and trying to rule out that difference being the root of the issue I'm seeing [with Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496401/sbnotificationhub-crash-on-return-from-registertemplatewithdevicetoken-in-testfl). Lots of conflicting old advice out there relating to this, so wanted to get some current insight on this specific device-id question.

Thanks.